# Java log parsing with logstash grok

Tags: java, logstash

This is my sample java log I tried to parse using Logstash

```
[#|2022-04-06T07:02:47.885+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=245;_ThreadName=sun-bpel-engine-thread-6;Process Instance Id=192.168.1.1:2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334;Service Assembly Name=CommComposite;BPEL Process Name=testname;|
Register BPEL ID : 192.168.1.1:2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334|#]
```

I tried to use this filter to parse it

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}
```

It seems this filter always left last line thus creating invalid log line. I suspect due to the [#| and |#] opening and closing tag.

Could anyone help me how to parse this kind of log so I can parse it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the grok pattern for the sample data provided by you:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\|%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\|(?<message>(.|\r|\n)*)
```

Output:

[image]